# Bachelor's Degree with LaTeX. Instructions for a beginner

Tags: tex-general

I want someone to direct me. I have a bachelor of science and I want to translate it in English with the LaTeX program.I was looking on internet to find something but the amount of information is vast. I want someone to show the very basics. My bachelor has the following layout and green background,A4 paper.

[image]

I have read the

[2]: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/certificates-with-latex/ but this does not help me very much.

Comment: For official documents my opinion is you are much better asking a well reputed translation company to perform a **certified translation**, or simply ask the issuing university if they can produce one in English. For translation, one does not need to produce an exact like-for-like certificate with seals, but a certified letter from the translation company along with the original will be legal in most countries. Doing it yourself and attempt to produce a like-for-like certificate may not well be legal depending on the country involved.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @MobiusPizza Will you write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Mobius Pizza answered the question in the comments the following way (just to convert the comment into an answer):

> For official documents my opinion is you are much better asking a well
>   reputed translation company to perform a **certified translation**, or
>   simply ask the issuing university if they can produce one in English.
>   For translation, one does not need to produce an exact like-for-like
>   certificate with seals, but a certified letter from the translation
>   company along with the original will be legal in most countries. Doing
>   it yourself and attempt to produce a like-for-like certificate may not
>   well be legal depending on the country involved.